# Why is beautifulsoup deleting so much stuff for this webpage?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beautifulsoup and trying to read some part of webpages into python. For multiple pages that works quite well. However, for this specific one Beautifulsoup is throwing away a lot of the text I would like to further process. Here is the example

```
html = requests.get(url).text

In [101]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [102]: import requests

In [103]: url = 'http://www.reuters.com/article/companyNewsAndPR/idUSTP13157220070102'

In [104]: html = requests.get(url).text

In [105]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='xml')

In [106]: soup
Out[106]: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--[if !IE]> This has been served from cache <![endif]--><!--[if !IE]> Request served from apache server: produs--i-0c9856522bc1925a7 <![endif]--><!--[if !IE]> Cached on Fri, 10 Aug 2018 13:08:25 GMT and will expire on Fri, 10 Aug 2018 13:23:24 GMT <![endif]--><!--[if !IE]> token: 8ba1c2fc-8894-48ea-ab7f-30d75c745528 <![endif]--><!--[if !IE]> App Server /produs--i-08940b2d65953b646/ <![endif]-->
```

A lot of the text is deleted. The `soup` object contains much much less and in particular the main text which is still there in `html`. I want to read afterwards all the `<p>` via

```
  text = list(soup.find_all('p'))
```

but this gives me an empty list as Beautifulsoup did delete all this parts. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the right element, in this case `div.StandardArticleBody_body > p`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.reuters.com/article/companyNewsAndPR/idUSTP13157220070102')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.h1.text)
print('-' * 80)
print()
for p in soup.select('div.StandardArticleBody_body > p'):
    print(p.text)
```

This prints:

```
UPDATE 1-TSMC plans five new advanced wafer plants -paper
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 (Adds TSMC’s comments)  
 TAIPEI, Jan 2 (Reuters) - TSMC (2330.TW) plans to build five new advanced 12-inch wafer plants on the island in the next few years, a local newspaper said on Tuesday, after a government move to allow companies to make more advanced chips in China.  

...and so on
```